# Need to send a hidden input value to mvc controller using angularjs

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a hidden input field that contains a value I need to send my mvc controller.

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/User/GetProjectsList' })
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {         
    $scope.workflow = [];
    $scope.Projects = data;
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('error');
});
```

And the hidden field is:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model='ProjectId' value="{{ProjectsObj.IDWorkflow}}"></input>
```

How can I send the value to the my controller and how do I get it in the controller? This is the method I had on the MVC controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetProjectsList()
{
    return Json();
}
```

Comment: directly attach the value to scope variable in angular so you can use it in the controller.

Comment: in the angular your do not need to have a hidden input.. but why? because we have controllers to connect to our API controllers when you want to send a command to your API controller your a model in your model put your hidden input value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with query string ?

```
var pID=$scope.ProjectId
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/User/GetProjectsList?ProjectID='+pID}).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {         
        $scope.workflow = [];

        $scope.Projects = data;

    }).
 error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     alert('error');
 })
```

;

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helped you ;)

```
 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.formDetails = {};
   $scope.sendToApi = function(){
       var model = {
          id: $scope.formDetails.id //this is my hidden input
          name: $scope.formDetails.name,
       }
       //and then send your model to API
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProjectId)
```

You Can Simply Pass Hidden Value  To Controller From View By using model value like above syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like AngularJS does not take in consideration hidden input when submitting forms, check this [issue for more details](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2574). But you can get your value in 2 ways:

1. classic way:

remove ng-model since has no sens with hidden type as explained above and add id:

```html
<input id="project_id" type="hidden" value="{{ProjectsObj.IDWorkflow}}"/>
```

in Javascript side you simply do:

```
var project_id = document.getElementById('45').value;
```

2. AngularJS way

since Angular ignores `hidden` elements, you can replace it with `type=text` and `display:none`:

```html
<input type="text" name="project_id" ng-model="projectID" style="display: none;"/>
```

and your javascript side using two way data-binding you can acces your ng-model variable:

```
var project_id = $scope.projectID;
```